# How do i install an openerp module from backend

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-6

```
'installable': True,
'auto_install': True,
'application': True,
'active':True,
```

I have added the above to my **openerp**.py and tried adding the module to an existing module and in both scenarios after that,I tried updating all my modules still the module wasn't installed.

I have tried running the query:

```
 update ir_module_module set state='to install' where name = mymodule;
```

That changed the state still didn't install the module

Comment: Can you try this in openerp workspace?
`./openerp-server --addons-path=../addons/,../web/addons/ -i <your module name> -d <your database name>`

Comment: Yup that did install the module thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At OpenERP workspace:

`./openerp-server --addons-path=../addons/... -i <your module name> -d <your database name>`